# SPARQL how to select number of all classes and instance without distinct?

Tags: sparql, rdf

I have problem to select data by using sparql query.

I made `.owl` file that structure is like as below:

```
Superclass
  - subclassA - instance1
  - subclassB
      - subclass1 - instance1
      - subclass2
             -subclass1 - instance1
  - subclassC
      - subclass1 - instance1
      - subclass2 - instance1
```

then i want to make result like:

```
+------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|   Class    |   sub1    |   sub2    |   sub3    | instance  |
+------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| Superclass | subclassA |           |           | instance1 |
| Superclass | subclassB | subclass1 |           | instance1 |
| Superclass | subclassB | subclass2 | subclass1 | instance1 |
| Superclass | subclassC |           |           | instance1 |
| Superclass | subclassC |           |           | instance2 |
+------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+\
```

I want to show the results, including instance value, from Class to leafclass.

so, I tried to make query like

```
SELECT ?Class ?sub1 ?sub2 ?sub3 ?instance
WHERE{
   ?instance rdf:type ?Class.
   ?instance tdf:type ?sub1.
   ?sub1 rdfs:subClassOf ?Class.
}
```

but, I have no idea. How do i fix it?

Comment: that's not possible with SPARQL. You created the "table" because you know the result in advance. With SPARQL you can't visualize such hierarchical data via a single query. Which by the way is never the task of a query language but the UI later on that represent the result. So the obvious suggestion, fetch the data that you need, then build and visualize the tree structure

Comment: indeed you could try to hard-code some query for your example, but then you should make use of nested `OPTIONAL`s clearly. Even then, I don't see why you could not post-process the result.